# Plotting a parameter 'map' in octave

Tags: plot, octave

I want to be able to plot a 2d grid of points onto a parameter plane. I want to plot each of the points, but plot it in a different way depending on what result the parameters/co-ordinates of that point lead to. The general effect I'm looking for is a sort of map, where one can point to a place in the plot and say 'In this region of parameter space, we see X  happening', like how a Pourbaix diagram works, but with more colour. Is there a fast and efficient way of doing this sort of grid plotting in octave?

Comment: do you have an example where we can see what you want to achieve. like a picture or some of that sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a specific example it's hard to give an exact answer but I think you just need to plot your grid with `imagesc()` and find an appropriate colormap.

Comment: That worked. I made [this](http://imageshack.us/a/img690/825/chuachaosmaprange5050sm.png) with it.